# Why :checked state of radio input does not change other div/label appearence?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a slider that have buttons(input radio) that when are checked they change how they look.

For example: For buttom number one(radio id 1) it should change the background color of div and/or label to purple.

But it is not working. Even if I check the input, nothing is changed. I tired different approaches to this, using class, using ID, using tag and nothing happens.

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

.index-btn,
.navbg div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: red;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-btn,
.navbg {
  display: flex;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  top: 30px;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 20px;
}

#slide1:checked~.bg-button1,
#testID {
  background-color: blue;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input type="radio" name="btn-index" id="slide1">
  <input type="radio" name="btn-index" id="slide2">
  <input type="radio" name="btn-index" id="slide3">
  <input type="radio" name="btn-index" id="slide4">
  <input type="radio" name="btn-index" id="slide5">
  <div class="navbg">
    <div class="bg-button1"></div>
    <div class="bg-button2"></div>
    <div class="bg-button3"></div>
    <div class="bg-button4"></div>
    <div class="bg-button5"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-btn">
    <label for="slide1" id="testID" class="index-btn"></label>
    <label for="slide2" class="index-btn"></label>
    <label for="slide3" class="index-btn"></label>
    <label for="slide4" class="index-btn"></label>
    <label for="slide5" class="index-btn"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using variables not in the posted code  `border-color: var(--buttonStroke);`

Comment: Oh, really, I was so focused in taking the code to here that I forgot that

Comment: `--mainColor` and `--glow` are not defined. Even if they were defined, the general sibling combinator `~` deals with sibling tags. You need to target a child tag of a sibling so use `#slide1:checked ~ .navbg .bg-button1`

Comment: I edited (I was kinda dizzy cause it was not working and forgot to simplify correctly). It workedm but it appears not to work when dealing with id, is that correct?

Comment: @Annie Alves Meaning, you want an output if click on the radio button, it will show *clicked* by showing this ```background-color: blue; box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px yellow;``` in the circle/radio button?

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to target a child tag of a sibling.
```

Using or calling the correct tag will get your desire output.

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

.index-btn,
.navbg div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: red;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-btn,
.navbg {
  display: flex;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  top: 30px;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 20px;
}

/* #slide1:checked~.bg-button1,
#testID {
  background-color: blue;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px yellow;
} */

input{
   display: none;
}
input[id="slide1"]:checked ~ div.navbg > .bg-button1{
  background-color: purple;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px yellow;
}
input[id="slide2"]:checked ~ div.navbg > .bg-button2 {
  background-color: blue;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px yellow;
}
input[id="slide3"]:checked ~ div.navbg > .bg-button3 {
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px yellow;
}
input[id="slide4"]:checked ~ div.navbg > .bg-button4 {
  background-color: green;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px yellow;
}
input[id="slide5"]:checked ~ div.navbg > .bg-button5 {
  background-color: orange;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <input type="radio" name="btn-index" id="slide1">
   <input type="radio" name="btn-index" id="slide2">
   <input type="radio" name="btn-index" id="slide3">
   <input type="radio" name="btn-index" id="slide4">
   <input type="radio" name="btn-index" id="slide5">
   <div class="navbg">
      <div class="bg-button1"></div>
      <div class="bg-button2"></div>
      <div class="bg-button3"></div>
      <div class="bg-button4"></div>
      <div class="bg-button5"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="nav-btn">
      <label for="slide1" id="testID" class="index-btn"></label>
      <label for="slide2" class="index-btn"></label>
      <label for="slide3" class="index-btn"></label>
      <label for="slide4" class="index-btn"></label>
      <label for="slide5" class="index-btn"></label>
   </div>
</div>
```